# Modify fixed-size array within List Element

Tags: arrays, list, go, interface, micro-optimization

I'm doing a micro-optimisation of my LRU cache solution in Golang where I'm using https://golang.org/pkg/container/list/.  My solution works by having a `map[int]*list.Element`, where each `list.List` `list.Element` is `[]int`, with `[0]` being key, and `[1]` being value.

I'm trying to move from `[]int` to `[2]int` for my optimisation, but I'm then running into the issue that modifying the fixed-size array, after `ee := e.Value.([2]int)` (note the `[2]int` type for fixed-size array), is no longer modifying the underlying values in the `list.Element`, unlike was the case w/ `ee := e.Value.([]int)` (note the `[]int` type), which I guess makes perfect sense, since slices are based on references, whereas fixed-size arrays are based on copied values.

I've tried stuff like `e.Value.([2]int)[1] = …`, as well as various combinations with `:= &e.Value…`, and casting from `[2]int` to `[]int`, but it all results in complier errors.

Q: ***Is there no way to use the `container/list` with an embedded array, and perform modifications of said fixed-size array in-place?***

Comment: Also tried the `[:]` trick — getting back `Line 38: invalid operation e.Value.([2]int)[:] (slice of unaddressable value)`

Answer (score 2):

As you already noted:

> I guess makes perfect sense, since slices are based on references, whereas fixed-size arrays are based on copied values

So if you want to make this work, you'll need to use references to your fixed-size arrays by storing **pointers** to the arrays instead of array values.

That way, you'll be able to modify the underlying array through the list element.

See here for a simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "container/list"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    l := list.New()

    // create a fixed size array and initialize it
    var arr [2]int
    arr[0] = 1
    arr[1] = 2
    // push a pointer to the array into the list
    elem := l.PushFront(&arr)
    // modify the stored array
    elem.Value.(*[2]int)[0] = 3
    // print the element from iterating the list
    for e := l.Front(); e != nil; e = e.Next() {
        fmt.Println(e.Value)
    }
    // print the underlying array, both are modified
    fmt.Println(arr)

}
```

**EDIT**

Note that this behaviour is not something specific to this list implementation, but rather related how type assertions work in the language itself.

See here:

https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interface_conversions

Quoting from that section (and adding emphasis of my own):

> The syntax borrows from the clause opening a type switch, but with an explicit type rather than the type keyword: `value.(typeName)` and **the result is a new value** with the static type typeName.

When using reference types, copying the value does not affect you cause copying a pointer value ends up allowing you to change the same underlying reference.

But when the array is a value itself, it does not make sense to assign to the copy. When you try to modify the array directly (without assigning the type assertion to a variable) Go would even catch this at compile time so that you don't assign to this "temporary" copy which would obviously be a mistake. That's how you got all your syntax errors when trying to do this.

To overcome this (if you don't want to use pointers) one possibility might be for you to implement your own `list`, borrowing from the implementation you are using but making your `Element`'s value an explicit `[2]int` instead of an interface.

That would remove the need to make the type assertion and you'll be able to modify the underlying array.

Comment: Note that once you use `*[2]int` there is no gain over using a pointer struct: `*struct { key, value int }`, and the struct will make the code clearer.

Comment: The problem here is efficiency.  I guess a pointer to the array would be slightly faster than a slice, but, conceptually at least, it does sound to be a bit slower than an embedded array within list.Element, esp. because of the extra garbage collection involved, imho.  Does this answer suggest that there is really no way to modify an embedded array within list.Element itself?  That would seem like a rather arbitrary restriction without any good rationale that I can think of.

Comment: @cnst: I edited my answer to expand on why it does not work when using non-reference values.

Comment: @eugenioy, oh, i see — the assertion creating a copy, now that starts to make at least some sense why no combination of dereferencing would work.  Now the only part left is whether there's a way to access any of this without an assertion, or to modify values in any other way (apart from making your own list implementation, of course)?  Otherwise, this still seems like a major performance limitation without any good rationale behind it.

Comment: @cnst, since it is stored as an "interface{}" there is no way to treat it as an array other than by type asserting. You could investigate around reflection and/or using functionality on the "unsafe" package, but all that might be more complex (and perhaps even less efficient) than just implementing your own list.